# Display response body on screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I would like to begin by saying that I very new to iOS development, so please, bare with me. I am working on an iOS app that will let my users log-in the website and view data that was returned from that request.

Currently, my plan looks like this:

- User enters "username" and "password" and presses "log-in"
- From there, entered data is extracted from those fields and is used to send HTTP request to a website.
- If username and password were correct and login was "Successful", then we move to another ViewController, where I will be displaying that data.

I have read few articles and documentation on how to work with Alamofire and URLSessions, but unfortunately, I am not able to figure out how to do what I am trying to do here.

What I am looking to do is:

-After user presses "Login" button, send HTTP request. Then I want to show response body from that request on screen. Note, I Don't want to print it in console, I want to display it on screen.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Some of my code below:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var field_Username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var field_Password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var button_Login: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button_Forgot: UIButton!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func onLoginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        doAlamofireRequest()
        
    }
    
    func doAlamofireRequest(){
        let url: String = "https://my.url.com/?xmlagent=true"
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Cookie": "zbs_lang=ukrainian; upassword=ce0bbe4d9406b2ecf0a768aed8527f69; ulogin=111111"
        ]
        AF.request(url, method: .post, headers: headers).response {response in
            if let data = response.data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
                print(dataString)
            }
        }
    }
```

With this code executed, I am able to print in the console a response body of XML data that I need to work with. How can I display this data on screen instead of console?

Comment: You could map your data to an structure (model) and access the properties, like: https://learnappmaking.com/codable-json-swift-how-to/ and so on, you have to have a component on your Storyboard to receive that data, like @IBOutlet var screenText: UILabel!, this way you can set a new value to your component like screenText.text = "SomeText". 
ps: "SomeText" can be chenged by a property of your model. Is that make any sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really just want to display your response on screen then just add a `UILabel` and assign your dataString to the label's `text` Property.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var field_Username: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var field_Password: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var button_Login: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var button_Forgot: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var responseLabel: UILabel!

    
    @IBAction func onLoginPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        doAlamofireRequest()
    }

    func doAlamofireRequest(){
        let url: String = "https://my.url.com/?xmlagent=true"
        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Cookie": "zbs_lang=ukrainian; upassword=ce0bbe4d9406b2ecf0a768aed8527f69; ulogin=111111"
        ]
        AF.request(url, method: .post, headers: headers).response { response in
            if let data = response.data, let dataString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
                self.label.text = dataString
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usually you would parse the XML and map it to your domain objects. Then depending on the received content you would create a user interface and populate it with the contents of your objects. For lists have a look at `UITableViewController` or `UICollectionViewController`

You can find many tutorials on the web on how to parse XML and how to create different user interfaces.

Comment: Yes, parsing XML and displaying parsed data is the plan here, but I couldn't figure out how to work with received data from HTTP response. How when I know how to handle things, I can move to the next step. Thank you very much